# nodejs url parse returns an extra undefined object

Tags: node.js, http, url

I'm writing a node js script to pull variables from the url line.

```
var http = require('http');//http package
var  url = require('url');// url package  
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){// creates server
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    var q = url.parse(req.url, true).query//pulls apart the url
    var temp = q.temp;
    res.write(temp);
    console.log(q.temp);
    res.end();
}).listen(7474)
```

Whenever it's tested, the script returns an extra variable of some kind. If I feed it http://localhost:7474/?temp=29 I get:

```
29
undefined
```

inside of my console. For some of my other functions in this script it causes the whole system to crash. And failure as
`The first argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type undefined`

Why is that? And how do I remedy the situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `res.write()` again followed by `res.end()`. The latter isn't supposed to return data.

Though it can supposedly return a string value in the first argument and then define the encoding format of the string as the second argument, but I've never tried that...

*"If data is specified, it is equivalent to calling response.write(data, encoding) followed by response.end(callback)."*

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback

```
var http = require('http');//http package
var  url = require('url');// url package
var list = ['0', '0', '1', '0'];  
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){// creates server
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    var q = url.parse(req.url, true).query//pulls apart the url
    var temp = q.temp;
    res.write(temp);
    console.log(q.temp);
    res.write(list[2] ); //testing artifact displayes them on a browser
    res.end();
}).listen(7474)
```

In you case there is really no reason to have both calls to `.write()` so I would just combine them...

`res.write(JSON.stringify([ temp, list[2] ]));`

Or

`res.write(JSON.stringify({ temp, listItem:list[2] }));`

**EDIT:**

After running this code myself you have a different issue here, which is giving you those confusing errors. Try this for now ...

```
var http = require('http');//http package
var  url = require('url');// url package
var list = ['0', '0', '1', '0'];  

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){// creates server
    if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
        res.writeHead(204);
        res.end();
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        var q = url.parse(req.url, true).query//pulls apart the url
        var temp = q.temp;
        res.write(temp);
        res.write(list[2]); //testing artifact displayes them on a browser
        res.end();
    }
}).listen(7474)

server.on('listening', function() {
    console.log('listening on port 7474')
});
```

The browser was making a 'default' request to `favicon.ico` after the page initial page loaded to do just that-load the favicon for each web page.  That request will crash your program because it doesn't include the query parameter `?temp=, which you aren't currently checking for.

The solution I provided is not workable solution for a production application, but this is clearly a little demo project, so it should do the job for your use case.

If you want to develop a larger, stable, production application you are going to have to reorganize things quite a bit. This could be a starting point if you don't want to use a framework...

https://adityasridhar.com/posts/how-to-use-nodejs-without-frameworks-and-external-libraries

I use the Express framework for all my node apps, which makes some of the default configuration faster and there are thousands of tutorials online to get you started...

https://medium.com/@purposenigeria/build-a-restful-api-with-node-js-and-express-js-d7e59c7a3dfb

- I just Googled these tutorials as an example, but you should do your own research to find the most suitable.

Comment: Ah, you're right about the error, but actually the initial request was completing fine. See my edit for more info

Comment: Thank you. I am testing it now, and when i run the script, it returns the following from the console log:
`    listening on port 7474
     29
     listening on port 7474`
Do you know if this will affect the script down the line in any way? Or what causes this?

Comment: When you say return, you mean in your browser or your logs? I removed the `console.logs()`

Comment: It should return `291` in your browser. First write `29` second `1`

Comment: No you should leave that in there actually, its a standard convention to identify when your server has started and is necessary debugging/monitoring node apps

Comment: I was taking about in the command line. I added simply the like `console.log(temp)` and it put listening before then after it. Which confused me because I thought that line would only be called once?

Comment: Yes sorry my mistake. I've updated the code now so that *'listening on port 7474'* message will only fire when initially starting the server not on every request. Good catch.

Comment: If my solution soled you problem effectively then please mark it as 'accepted' or let me know if there's anything else I can help you with. Thanks!